# Prove that this operator is a bounded linear operator and find its norm. Is the norm achieved on a unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following operator: $A:C_{L^2[0,1]} \to C_{L^1[0,1]}, Ax(t)=t^2x(t)$

I was able to prove linearity, but I don't really know what to do next.

Comment: You need to show that (1) there is some $L$ such that $\|Ax\|_1 \le L \|x\|_2$ for all $x$ and (2) find the smallest such $L$ (the norm). Finally, (3) you need to see if there is some point $x$ (that satisfies $\|x\|_2 \le 1$) such that $\|Ax\|_1 = \|A\|$.

Comment: I presume this is homework, did your classwork not cover the ideas here?

Comment: @copper.hat It's been almost a year so not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder,s inequality $\|Ax\|=\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1t^2|x(t)|dt\leq\sqrt{\int\limits_0^1t^4dt}\sqrt{\int\limits_0^1|x(t)|^2dt}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt5}\|x\|$, so $\|A\|\leq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt5}$. On the other hand $\|A\|\geq\dfrac{\|Ax_0\|}{\|x_0\|}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt5}$ when choosing $x_0(t)=\sqrt5t^2$.

Comment: I'm a little confused why we use ≤ over = in some cases, for example in the very first step.

Comment: This is a Holder's inequality for integrals (aka Cauchy-Schwarz inequality): $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1|f|\cdot |g|dt\leq\sqrt{\int\limits_0^1|f|^2dt}\sqrt{\int\limits_0^1|g|^2dt}$

Comment: Got it. I'm accepting the answer, but do you have any ideas about the unit ball question?

Comment: Function $x_0(t)$ lies in the unit ball